# I have to click the button twice for it to work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, focus

So I have a button in my app and an edittext. When I click the button and write something in the edittext, a textview changes. It all works as it should except for one thing. I have to click on the button twice to make it work (only the first time I open activity). The very first time after I open activity I press the button and nothing happens, after that it works as it should.

I already did my research on this and as far as I know the thing that is causing trouble is focus, but I tried a few things and nothing worked.

Button XML code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox25"
    android:text="@string/addMaterial"
    android:onClick="submitQuantityButton" >
</Button>
```

Edittext XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" >
</EditText>
```

I tried adding android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to button XML, I also tried adding requestFocus to button XML and it still doesn't work. I also removed the requestFocus from edittext and it doesn't work. I'm running out of ideas what else to try.

onClick method:

```
public void submitQuantityButton (View v){
    Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    final Spinner sItems = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Context context = this;
    final CheckBox cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    final CheckBox cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    final CheckBox cb33 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox33);
    final CheckBox cb30 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox30);
    final CheckBox cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
    final CheckBox cb7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
    final CheckBox cb9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
    final CheckBox cb10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox10);
    final CheckBox cb11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox11);
    final CheckBox cb12 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox12);

    //
    final AlertDialog.Builder emptyETextErrorBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setMessage("Please enter a value before pressing this button");
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = sItems.getSelectedItemPosition();
            EditText quantityEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            switch (position){
            case 0:
                AlertDialog.Builder spinnerErrorBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setMessage("Please choose an item from the list above and then enter a certain value");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog spinnerError = spinnerErrorBuilder.create();
                spinnerError.show();
                break;
            case 1:
                String item1 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item1.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb4.setText("Elaborate Totem (" + item1 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                String item2 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item2.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb5.setText("Pile of Crystalline Dust (" + item2 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                String item3 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item3.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb33.setText("Pile of Crystalline Dust (" + item3 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                String item4 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item4.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb30.setText("Pile of Crystalline Dust (" + item4 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                String item5 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item5.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb6.setText("Powerful Venom Sac (" + item5 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                String item6 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item6.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb7.setText("Vial of Powerful Blood (" + item6 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                String item7 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item7.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb9.setText("Ancient Bone (" + item7 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                String item8 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item8.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb10.setText("Armored Scale (" + item8 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                String item9 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item9.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb11.setText("Vicious Claw (" + item9 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                String item10 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item10.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    cb12.setText("Vicious Fang (" + item10 + "/250)");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say a few things, have you tried to clear focus?

Comment: yes, i tried that but I forgot to mention it in the question

Comment: Wait, where should I try clearfocus? I only tried adding it to edittext in XML file.

Comment: Post your `onClick`...maybe you are doing something in there

Comment: I did, check the edited post

Comment: Here is an answer I have given to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074852/setonclicklistener-on-imageview-needs-to-click-two-times-in-order-to-work/56047741#56047741

Comment: Have you get the answer..? I Also have the same issue.

Comment: Here is a better approach to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/11799891/6874510

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured out what caused the problem, by myself. I can't believe I missed such an obvious issue. The thing that caused problem wasn't focus, but the method itself. In my XML file I called onClick method by android:onClick="onClick" and then I also added a buttonlistener inside the onClick method to java code.

All I did was remove the buttonlistener and there's no more double clicking neccessary! So if anyone has this problem in future simply make sure you don't have an onClick method AND buttonlistener at the same time.

Wrong code:

```
public void submitQuantityButton (View v){

submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
.
.
. //REST OF THE CODE
```

To make it work I simply deleted the onclick listener, leaving only:

```
public void submitQuantityButton (View v){
.
.
. //REST OF THE CODE
```

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason. I don't have two onClicks, I only add one in my code. It does change the state of the button to focussed first before working, so I am simply going to extract the content of the onClick method and call it both on the onClick event and on the onFocus event. Just like an onClick with multiple buttons, catch all onFocus events with an onFocusChangeListener and then check if the button is selected.

Comment: can't believe, exactly same for me :/ grrr databinding...  :) ‍♂️

Comment: worked! I made a similar mistake of defining click listener inside that another click listener ‍♂️

Answer (score 51):

My problem was the `Button` XML defining:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Remove this attribute and the button doesn't require being touched twice. It appears as though the first touch is consumed to assign focus on the button and the second then triggers the `OnClickListener`.

Note that the Button works without issue with the `android:focusable="true"` attribute.

Comment: Changing `focusableInTouchMode` was the solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am using an imageview but this is not working for me?? What should i do?

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are inflating view to another one, try to set on parent view:

```
view.setFocusable(false);
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime I had it problem when click on **btn** or **txt** or **edt** on the fragment, and realy helps use instead **.setOnClickListener()** need **.setOnTouchListener** like this example:

```
txtClose.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                // do staff...
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once
**UPDATED**

`override` `onResume` method in your `activity`
and then clear focus from your edittext and set focus to your main layout

```
edittext.clearFocus();
layout.requestFocus();
```

or

```
button.requestFocus();
```

if the problem is with virtual keyboard it might help you

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside your `Activity` tag put this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: try `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your layout that contains `button` and `edittext`

Comment: Added those 2 in my relative layout (I think that's what you meant) and it sadly still won't work

Comment: I did edittext.clearfocus() but it doesn't work. But I couldn't add layout.requestFocus() (eclipse underlined it with red)

Comment: did u try to set focus on your button?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing it in XML (requestFocus) and it didn't work. After all this time trying to focus it I started thinking maybe after all it isn't a focus problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP. I tried all the focus-related suggestions, but none of them worked every time for me.

I tried removing the `NavigationDrawer` from my layout, but that didn't work.

Lastly, I tried replacing my `CoordinatorLayout` with a `LinearLayout` and now my buttons click first time every time. Could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following  lines :

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/sauvegarder"
    android:text="Sauvegarder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fontmargin"
    style="@style/edit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />
```

in my xml file it works perfectly !

Answer (score -1):

Simply use getText() to get text from EditText
And then set text of TextView using setText().