# setOnClickListener on imageview needs to click two times in order to work

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, listener

I have `ImageView` in my activity with the following properties i have innitialized the imageview and also set `OnClickListener` on `ImageView`, but when i click on Imageview for the first time, onlick event doesnot work but when i click on Imageview for the second time it works

```
                  <ImageView
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:id="@+id/switchIcon"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp" />
```

i have following code in my activity class file :

```
ImageView switchIcon;
switchIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switchIcon);


 switchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v) {

                    if (switchStatus.equals("video")) {
                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    } else if (switchStatus.equals("image")) {
                        if (requestData.get("video_link").equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Video Found for this Recipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            switchStatus = "video";
                            LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mPlayer.play();
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_photo_size_select_actual_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                        }
                    } else {
                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    }
            }
        });
```

I also tried adding the `OnTouchListener()` as `OnClickListener()` was not working with this, but `OnTouchListener()` is also not working with ImageView it also needs two clicks in order to get onclick event

```
 switchIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if (switchStatus.equals("video")) {
                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    } else if (switchStatus.equals("image")) {
                        if (requestData.get("video_link").equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Video Found for this Recipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            switchStatus = "video";
                            LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mPlayer.play();
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_photo_size_select_actual_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                        }
                    } else {
                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I also tried changing `ImageView` to `ImageButton` but it also does not help me out, please tell me what action can i perform to solve this problem.

Comment: what is default value of switchStatus

Comment: the default value of switchStatus="" , is blank

Comment: android:focusable="false", Why this line ?

Comment: i just added that line in order to check whether there is problem with focus, cause on first click it is getting focus and on second click the Onclick Event occurs

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your conditions and click is getting called on each click, try following code (show toast on click) :

```
 switchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClick(View v) {

                    if (switchStatus.equals("video")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "switchStatus changed to video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    } else if (switchStatus.equals("image")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "switchStatus image has clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (requestData.get("video_link").equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Video Found for this Recipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            switchStatus = "video";
                            LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mPlayer.play();
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_photo_size_select_actual_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                        }
                    } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "switchStatus was blank, changed to image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        switchStatus = "image";
                        LayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LayoutVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPlayer.pause();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp).into(switchIcon);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: yea there was a problem in my condition I set switchStatus default value as image and it start working fine

Answer (score 0):

I put this answer here in case some one lands on this same problem and has the same cause as mine. 
    The cause of mine was another view in my layout which retained focus after an on touch event on it because I forgot to change the return value from false to true when implementing its on touch listener. The consequence was that I had to click my image view twice after touching the other view for focus to be returned to the layout before the onclick event on the image view is called.
    So in general ensure that no other view in layout retains focus perhaps after an on touch event on it in which case the implementation of its onTouch method should return true and not the default false value.