# Inside SwipeRefreshLayout button click not working for the first time

Tags: android, buttonclick, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to do button click action inside `SwipeRefreshLayout` but it is working for the second time but not for the first time click.

Can anyone suggest whats wrong with it?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="38dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:contentPaddingBottom="16dp"
            app:contentPaddingLeft="0dp"
            app:contentPaddingRight="0dp">

            // My button code is here
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loadMore"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerViewJS"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:text="Load More"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Got the id of it using Butter Knife:

```
@BindView(R.id.loadMore)
Button loadMore;
```

My button click action is here:

```
@OnClick(R.id.loadMore)
public void onLoadMoreClick() {
    loadMoreData();
}
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261876/i-have-to-click-the-button-twice-for-it-to-work) but no use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did your log inside your button and which version of support library are you using ? `27.1.0` ?

Comment: and secondly your button is `android:visibility="gone"` , in xml ..there might be some logic too !! you need to post your code !!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Santanu, Am using 26.0.2, and am showing that when there are more than 10 records. There is no issue with showing this button.

Comment: are you sure its the second time the button is actually getting clicked ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I tried to put this outside of it it's working for the first click

Comment: But what's wrong when I kept in `SwipeRefreshLayout` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166884/discussion-between-shylendra-madda-and-santanu-sur).

Comment: i will have a look in my device, then i will update !!

Comment: How did you notice it doesn't work first time? Did you put any debug log inside your `loadMoreClick` function to check?

Comment: Yes, While debugging for the first time it's not going inside, but when I click again the log printed..  @ReazMurshed

Comment: @SantanuSur Can you please help me out?