# AutoCompleteTextView click listener is not working perfectly

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am making an android application where I am using the `AutoCompleteTextView` and trying to set the onClickListener for reset the entered value on click on `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Issue is that I have two `AutoCompleteTextView` so when I entered text in first `AutoCompleteTextView` then second `AutoCompleteTextView` then click on first `AutoCompleteTextView` then it is not calling OnClickListener on the first `AutoCompleteTextView`

Any idea why this is behaving such weird ?

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/fromStationEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_rail"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textSize="16sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

ClickListener on `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
// reset the value when user click on this view
source_stn_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        source_stn_txt.setText("");
    }
});

// reset the value when user click on this view
dest_stn_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dest_stn_txt.setText("");
    }
});

source_stn_txt.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        source = source_stn_txt.getText().toString().trim();
        dest_stn_txt.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you binded any values in your `AutoCompleteTextview` ?

Comment: try to set this listener : "setOnItemClickListener"

Comment: @GrIsHu Yes I have picked the value from suggestion list

Comment: Check out Sam's answer here:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790573/onclick-event-is-not-triggering-android

Comment: As i told you that onClickEvent is not for `AutocompleteTextView` you are supposed to implemeted `onItemclick` for your both views.

Comment: @GrIsHu onItemclick is for different purpose, I am not click on item to pick the values. I am simply click on that view

Comment: @SoundsDangerous Yes that is the issue, Nice you found awesome answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that helped @Williams is: [onClick event is not triggering | Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790573/onclick-event-is-not-triggering-android). Also posted above in the comments. I'm glad you found your solution!

> When a user interacts with a UI element the various listeners are called in a top down order. (For example: OnTouch -> OnFocusChange -> OnClick.) If a listener has been defined (with setOn...Listener) and it consumes this event: the lower priority listeners will not be called. By its nature the first time you touch an EditText it receives focus with OnFocusChangeListener so that the user can type. The action is consumed here therefor OnClick is not called. Each successive touch doesn't change the focus so the event trickles down to the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) not `OnClickListener`.

```
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromStationEdit);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu"};

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);

    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    adapter.getItem(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Williams Show how have you implemeted the click listener for your both `AutoCompleteTextView` ?

Comment: Yes I have added the code in question. please see there

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared items to complete in your Strings.xml. If not, do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">AutoComplete</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="auto_complete">AutoComplete</string>
<string name="multi_auto_complete">Multi AutoComplete</string>
<string-array name="list_of_countries">
  <item >USA</item>
  <item >Uk</item>
  <item >Canada</item>
  <item >Australia</item>
  <item >France</item>
  <item >Italy</item>
  <item >China</item>
  <item >Japan</item>
  <item >Spain</item>
  </string-array>

</resources>
```

Or declare in your class Activity:

```
AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;

String item[]={
"January", "February", "March", "April",
"May", "June", "July", "August",
"September", "October", "November", "December"
};
```