# Inflating an AutoCompleteSupportFragement in an editText onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, google-places-api, onclicklistener

I am trying to inflate an AutoCompleteSupportFragment which uses Google Places API, in an onClick event of an editText.

I want to inflate that fragment when the editText is clicked, so that the user might enter a location, select from the suggestions in the auto complete fragment and the location name will be shown on the editText.

I checked this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790573/onclick-event-is-not-triggering-android), but it didnt work for me.

places_auto_complete_fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment" />
```

how I am trying to inflate it

```
sourceEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.places_auto_complete_fragment,addTripLinearLayout,false);
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Kudo's @arnavJJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Intent builder instead fragment in editText....**

initialise on Oncreate

```
   // Initialize Places.
   Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "***YOUR API KEY***");

   // Create a new Places client instance.
   PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

**Then use below code on edittext on click event...**

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
// Start the autocomplete intent.
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer the below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045772/10579969...

> **if you are using only fragment please refer below code**

```
       AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setCountry("IN");    //country type
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)); 
   //to indicate the types of place data that you want to get.
```

Comment: For me (AutocompleteSupportFragment)getChildFragmentManager() worked. getSupportFragmentManager() won't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. AutocompleteSupportFragment presents a search box button to the user, which presents a search box UI when clicked
2. Inflating the layout loads the UI but you have to add it to your view in order to make it visible.